# ReactJS Tab Navigation Delay After Multiple Iterations Despite Consistent API Response Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented tab functionality using Pure Javascript with out using any libraries

When I tried to navigate one tab to another tab in ReactJS

```
export const menuConfig: { [key: string]: any } = {
  home: {
    tabId: 'home',
    tabPath: `/${HomeViews.HOME}`,
    tabTitle: 'Home',
  },
    Employee: {
        tabId: 'employee',
        tabPath: `/${EmpViews.EMPLOYEES}`,
        tabTitle: 'Employee',
    },
    Student: {
        tabId: 'student',
        tabPath: `/${StudentViews.STUDENT}`,
        tabTitle: 'Student',
    }
};
```

Initially it is giving speed response, but after 7 to 8 times of navigation, tab navigation is getting delayed even though api response time is same.

Tried clearing cache and tried incognito mode still getting similar issue(not able to use any third party plugins to solve the problem, but it can be customizable)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You didn't post any code for your pure js implementation.  I'm not sure how you can expect anyone to offer any kind of help.  The fact this received several votes suggests you're padding it yourself to get attention.